# CakePHP .htaccess mod_rewrite configuration to exclude a particular folder/url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

I have a CakePHP installation in a sub folder in my server, I want to install another application inside that subfolder:

```
root/public_html/subfolder/cake/
root/public_html/subfolder/app/
```

etc. now I need a custom application installed there:

```
root/public_html/subfolder/my_custom_application/
```

I have something like this in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I configure it to exclude the "my_custom_application" folder from that rules?

I tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    ((?!my_custom_application).*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I get this:

```
Error:  The requested address '/y_custom_application' was not found on this server.
```

Thanks in advance.

Mauricio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to Exclude a Directory from CakePHP Routing:

I ran into the same problem as you. I struggled, but finally found something that worked. 

*(I'm replying because the answer above didn't work for me, but this did).*

**My directory structure:**

```
root/public_html/app/
root/public_html/lib/
root/public_html/plugins/
root/public_html/vendors/
root/public_html/directory_to_exclude/
```

**What I added to CakePHP's default routing:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_to_exclude/(.*)
```

Effectively, I needed to allow people to access the subfolder separately (since that has a separate application). Also, in my case, I'm serving a CakePHP application by default from the root directory. 

So here's what my CakePHP 2.x htaccess looks like:

**Updated .Htaccess (this works for me)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_to_exclude/(.*)
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In your case, I understand you need this to work in a subfolder; here's my adjusted htaccess I didn't have a chance to test this, but I believe this (or something close) will work:

**The Final Product (for a subfolder)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/directory_to_exclude/(.*)
   RewriteRule    ^$ subfolder/app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) subfolder/app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It seems to work. but not working in CakePHP 3.x please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Put this before the `RewriteRule` lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_custom_application
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, but I still have the same error:
Error:  The requested address '/my_custom_application' was not found on this server.
this time with the "m" of "my_custom_application"

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace dir_to_exclude by your dir name.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:dir_to_exclude)(?:$|/)
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:dir_to_exclude)(?:$|/)
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you want to have more than one excluded directory you have to add them separated by |additional_dir_to_exclude

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:dir_to_exclude|additional_dir_to_exclude)(?:$|/)
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:dir_to_exclude|additional_dir_to_exclude)(?:$|/)
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```