# How to Exclude a Directory/File from CakePHP Routing?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to implement SabreDav into CakePHP (3.0). I've put the calendarserver.php file from the SabreDav package into my cake webroot. Now I'm able to access http://localhost/myproject/calendarserver.php . This page contains a link, which redirects me to http:://localhost/myproject/calendarserver.php/principals . Now the problem is when I click the link Cake tells me that the **PrincipalsController is missing**. I don't need any controller and want to handle the url after my calendarserver.php file without cake.

I've changed my .htaccess like the solution of [CakePHP .htaccess mod_rewrite configuration to exclude a particular folder/url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249885/cakephp-htaccess-mod-rewrite-configuration-to-exclude-a-particular-folder-url) , but the same error appears again.

I also tried to copy the sabre folder one steph higher than the webroot (in the project folder) and modify my .htacces to

**RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/? (sabre)/(.*)**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following entry in your .htaccess file and see if it helps:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(sabre).* [NC]
```

Comment: Still the same error: "PrincipalsController could not be found" when I access http://localhost/sabre/calendarserver.php/principals/