# How to run a custom project folder in cakephp application root

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a project in cakephp 2 which contains frontend, admin and api sections. Files are in public_html folder of server. Now I need to run a separate php project containing mainly html and javascript inside the root of cakephp 2. Is that possible?

Comment: This question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9236536/4043593
please check.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your httpd.conf

```
RewriteRule ^(foldername)($|/) - [L]
```

Thanks