# wordpress installed in cakephp subfolder on iis window server

Tags: wordpress, cakephp, iis-8, cakephp-2.6

i have installed cakephp 2.6 version on microsoft window server 6.2 IIS service 8.5
in that i have installed wordpress blog in sub directory under app folder

```
|_ cakePHP
|     |_ app
|     |_ blog
|     |_ lib
|     |_plugins
```

every thing working correctly in cakephp app also wordpress blog is also working
fine if we hit baseurl/blog/
index page appeared correctly.

But when we change the setting in wordpress blog parmalink setting and make prety url like
https://www.baseurl.com/blog/hello-world/
it give 404 error but its working with plain url like
https://www.baseurl.com/blog/?p=1

but i need the prety parmalink URL like
https://www.baseurl.com/blog/hello-world/

i search many article for this also find many but no answer is working with the window server with cakephp
as you all are aware .htacces is not work on iis 8 so i create web.config file in root folder of cakephp

```
|_ cakePHP
|     |_ app
|     |_ blog
|     |_ lib
|     |_plugins
|     |_web.config
```

code of root folder/above web.config is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
    
                    <!--# Exclude requests already going to /subfolder to avoid an infinite loop-->
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^blog.*$" />
                        <action type="None" />
                    </rule>
    
    
                    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                    </rule>
    
                    <rule name="Exclude direct access to app/webroot/*" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^app/webroot/c$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="None" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(geet_jewellery,img, css, files, js, favicon)" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(blog|buyanddelight|crm_geet|geet_jewellery1|geet_jewellery|img|css|files|js|favicon.ico)(.*)$" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="Rewrite requested file/folder to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
    
    
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultPath="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Indexhome_.htm">
                <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="4" path="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Indexhome_.htm" responseMode="File" />
            </httpErrors>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

and the web.config which placed in root folder of blog directory where all wordpress file is below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: https://www.buyanddelight.com/blog" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule>
        
        
        </rules>
    
     </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I found many answers, but all are incomplete because some of them without cakephp some of them without wordpress and someof them without IIS server rest was not working so please help me out from this.

you can also refer below link to clarify my question as it can achieved by .htaccess but I am not able to find answer for IIS server web.config

[image: enter link description here]

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Try to keep a security threat like wordpress as far away from any proper framework as you possibly can. Maybe put it on a subdomain and redirect to that. At-least thats something i would do in your case. But you could just put the entire blog folder in your webroot folder, the pathing should be working beter from there i gues haven't tested it tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the answer which work for me below is the code which work for me on iis server. create a web.config file as well under blog folder and put the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question and welcome to SO! In this scenario I would move Wordpress away from your CakePHP library. Your CakePHP environment would become extreme vulnerable. Wordpress has some security flaws that will affect your CakePHP environment aswell when you keep it as a subfolder. File inclusion, SQL injection, cross-site scripting and malware often comes together with dirty plugins and themes.

Comment: yes i can also move wordpress folder into webroot but the question remain same how i will get the prety url like https://www.baseurl.com/blog/hello-world/ ............if is their any way to achive this like web.config or etc let me know.

Comment: have any one find answer of my question

Comment: In case you move it to your webroot you can use the default .htaccess that Wordpress uses (https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess). Afterwards you can define how your URL should look like from within Wordpress. If you don't move it to webroot you should exclude the subfolder in the .htaccess CakePHP uses (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249885/cakephp-htaccess-mod-rewrite-configuration-to-exclude-a-particular-folder-url)

Comment: as i already said my cakephp application is on IIS WINDOW SERVER so .htacces will not work..... only WEB.CONFIG will work so please answer accordingly as i tried above but .htaccess is not effecting any thing

Comment: can anyone answer please